# How to convert a object from one JpaRepository into another JpaRepository

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem with one functionality in my spring app. I have 2 tables in the same database, both contains the same type of data (id,title,description and date). And I can get the data from one table but don't know how to insert into 2nd table.

In my @Service layer i can get the data from table A. But dont know how to convert into another class object (both classes contain the samne data)

Injected JpaRepositories

```
private TasksRepository theTasksRepository;

private TasksRepositoryArchive theTasksRepositoryArchive;
```

And there's code to get the object from table A (TasksRepository - JpaRepository)

```
    public Tasks findById(int theId) {

        //Check if value is null or not null
        Optional<Tasks> result = theTasksRepository.findById(theId);

        Tasks theTask = null;
        if (result.isPresent())
        {
            //if value is not null
            theTask = result.get();
        }
        else
        {
            //if value is null
            throw new RuntimeException("Task with given ID couldn't be found " +theId );
        }

        return theTask;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Define 2 entities, one for each table. To copy data, create an instance of the 2nd type and, copy properties, save. To copy properties there are many ways: you cann call each getter and setter manually, you can use some libraries like Dozer or MapStruct. Don't forget to set ID to null.

2) If you want to have an archive of changes, use libraries that help to implement it. For instance, consider using [Enverse](https://hibernate.org/orm/envers/).

Comment: I've already had 2 entites for each table. Decided to call getters and setters to copy data, as you suggest and everythink work as it should. Thank you for advice.